# PHP Mailer - 454 TLS connection failed

Tags: php, email, ssl, phpmailer

On my page I have a contact form which uses PHP Mailer.
At the beginning, for testing purposes only, I used it with my Gmail account. Everything worked like a charm. Then I decided to change the e-mail service from Gmail to one which comes from my hosting provider. Then the problems have started. Every time I attempt to send an email, an exception occurs:

```
2020-05-13 20:53:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-05-13 20:53:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 ready for tls
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2020-05-13 20:53:44 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-05-13 20:53:44 SERVER -> CLIENT: 454 TLS connection failed: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (#4.3.0)
2020-05-13 20:53:44 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 454 TLS connection failed: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure (#4.3.0)
```

This is my code for sending an e-mail:

```
<?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

    require 'PHPMailer.php';
    require 'SMTP.php';
    require 'Exception.php';

    class Mailer
    {
        private $mail;

        public function __construct($host, $user, $password, $port = 587)
        {
            $this->mail = new PHPMailer();
            try
            {
                $this->mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;  
                $this->mail->CharSet    = "UTF-8";
                $this->mail->isSMTP();
                $this->mail->Host       = $host;
                $this->mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
                $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
                $this->mail->Username   = $user;
                $this->mail->Password   = $password;
                $this->mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
                $this->mail->Port       = $port;
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo "Exception: " . $e;
            }
        }

        public function Send($from, $alias, $to, $subject, $body, $cc)
        {
            try
            {
                $this->mail->setFrom($from, $alias);
                $this->mail->addAddress($to);

                $this->mail->isHTML(true);
                $this->mail->Subject = $subject;
                $this->mail->Body    = $body;

                if($cc !== '')
                {
                    $this->mail->AddCC($cc);
                }

                if(!$this->mail->send())
                {
                    die($this->mail->ErrorInfo);
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

I suppose I configure PHP Mailer wrongly when it comes to TLS/SSL, as I am pretty newbie to this. It may be an expedient information that my webpage uses TLS 1.3 encryption

Comment: The first place you should look for any issues relating to PHPMailer is [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#using-encryption). PHPMailer's use of TLS is completely unrelated to the TLS configuration of your web page, though it works fine with TLSv1.3 if your PHP installation supports it. I'd also recommend that you learn how to use composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tip, if it works, don't forget a vote to strengthen. Let's go to the settings ...

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => false
    )
);
```

Remember that this is a palliative solution to work immediately, but I recommend investigating the problem. Another detail do tests using ports 465 and 587 sometimes it can be that!

```
$mail->Port = "587";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
```

Another thing I didn't understand ... why would I be using **$ this->mail->SMTPSecure** twice?

```
 $this->mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
 $this->mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
```

Comment: The port changing trick did the job. Perfect simplicity! Thank you very much :) And of course setting SMTPSecure twice was my oversight.

Comment: Great that the tip helped. Success!

Comment: Please don't suggest that disabling certificate verification is a solution, it's only encouraging others to do the same when it actually makes the situation worse, hiding what may be potentially bigger problems.